# DSL Seed Job - How to update the existing job using DSL in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

Can someone tell me how to update the existing Jenkins job through DSL seed job.
I found ignore changes to be selected for updating the existing job , but its not working its not doing anything on my existing job. Is there any other way or am I missing anything here for updating the existing job.

[Below is the screenshot from my seed job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQj9.png)

Answer (score 2):

**You can't "import" existing jobs** and control them with the Job DSL plugin.

If you want to use Job DSL, then you need to re-define jobs from scratch and specify them in DSL.

Comment: Thanks Alex that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

- Ignore missing files:               Unselect
- Action for existing jobs and views:   Ignore changes Unselect
- Action for removed jobs:          Ignore
- Action for removed views:         Ignore
- Action for removed config files:    Ignore

Do above setting and retrigger seed job. It will update existing jobs.